# How to sort bar in nvd3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 multibar chart in my application. Its working fine. Here i need to sort the bars based on the values(I mean in ascending/descend manner). Is there any inbuilt function available for sorting in nvd3. Or how can I achieve the sorting thing.

```
nv.addGraph(function() {

  var chart;
  chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
    .margin({bottom: 100})
    .transitionDuration(300);

  chart.options( {delay: 1200});

  chart.multibar
    .hideable(false);

  chart.xAxis
      //.axisLabel("Modules")
      .rotateLabels(45);

  chart.yAxis
   .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + "%"; });


  d3.select('#' + "barChart" + ' svg')
      .datum(data)
     .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

  return chart;
});
```

Comment: I am afraid there is no inbuilt function, Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114534/sort-bars-on-nvd3-charts) or [this one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034973/nvd3-stacked-area-chart-looks-glitchy-how-to-fix)

Comment: @shabeer90 hi tnx for u r response. U mention in horizontal bar. In my case its vertical

Comment: Check the second link, it shows how to sort the data and pass it into the chart.

Comment: @shabeer90..thanks it working right for me with some alteration in data. Can i able to put one button for sorting in the same chart ?

Comment: Yes you can add a button, Have a look at this [Question & Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689157/nvd3-how-to-refresh-the-data-function-to-product-new-data-on-click/24695324#24695324), it might give you an idea of how it can be done

Comment: @shabeer90 i wanna sort the stacked bar with out repainting. Is it possible to rearrange the bar while sorting

Comment: There's an open enhancement request: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1711

Answer (score 0):

To sort bars in nvd3 I did this approach. First i tried with unsorted data, manually sort the data and checked whether it's working or not . After that I use sort function to sort the data dynamically.

```
function iniChart(data){
  nv.addGraph(function() {  
  var chart;
  chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
        .margin({bottom: 100})
        .transitionDuration(300);

      chart.options( {delay: 1200});
      chart = nv.models.multiBarChart().stacked(true).showControls(false);  
      chart.multibar
        .hideable(false);

      chart.xAxis
          .axisLabel("Modules")
          .rotateLabels(45);

      chart.yAxis
       .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + "%"; });

      d3.select('#' + "barChart" + ' svg')
          .datum(data)
         .call(chart);

      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

      chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

      return chart;
  });
 }

 iniChart(data);

 function sortedChart(){
data.forEach(function(d){ if(d.key=="Completion"){
    d.values.sort(function(a,b){
         return a.y - b.y;
        })
} })

data.forEach(function(d){ if(d.key=="NonCompletion"){
 d.values.sort(function(a,b){       
         return b.y - a.y;
        })
} })

console.log("Check Data::"+JSON.stringify(data))
     iniChart(data);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this problem. You need to sort your bars in the **multiBarHorizontal** function. Add the variable **sortDescending** (plus a accessor method for it). Replace:

```
x
.domain(xDomain || d3.merge(seriesData).map(function(d) { return d.x }))
.rangeBands(xRange || [0, availableHeight], groupSpacing);
```

with:

```
        if (sortDescending) {
            x.domain(xDomain || d3.merge(seriesData).sort(function (a, b) { return Math.abs(b.y) - Math.abs(a.y) }).map(function(d) { return d.x }))
        } else {
            x.domain(xDomain || d3.merge(seriesData).map(function(d) { return d.x }))
        }
        x.rangeBands(xRange || [0, availableHeight], groupSpacing);
```

And when you call nv.addGraph, use the **.sortDescending** accessor:

```
.sortDescending(true)
```

The complete multiBarHorizontal function should then look like this:

```
nv.models.multiBarHorizontal = function() {
"use strict";

//============================================================
// Public Variables with Default Settings
//------------------------------------------------------------

var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0}
    , width = 960
    , height = 500
    , id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) //Create semi-unique ID in case user doesn't select one
    , container = null
    , x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    , y = d3.scale.linear()
    , getX = function(d) { return d.x }
    , getY = function(d) { return d.y }
    , getYerr = function(d) { return d.yErr }
    , forceY = [0] // 0 is forced by default.. this makes sense for the majority of bar graphs... user can always do chart.forceY([]) to remove
    , color = nv.utils.defaultColor()
    , barColor = null // adding the ability to set the color for each rather than the whole group
    , disabled // used in conjunction with barColor to communicate from multiBarHorizontalChart what series are disabled
    , stacked = false
    , showValues = false
    , showBarLabels = false
    , valuePadding = 60
    , groupSpacing = 0.1
    , valueFormat = d3.format(',.2f')
    , delay = 1200
    , xDomain
    , yDomain
    , xRange
    , yRange
    , duration = 250
    , dispatch = d3.dispatch('chartClick', 'elementClick', 'elementDblClick', 'elementMouseover', 'elementMouseout', 'elementMousemove', 'renderEnd')
    , sortDescending = false
    ;

//============================================================
// Private Variables
//------------------------------------------------------------

var x0, y0; //used to store previous scales
var renderWatch = nv.utils.renderWatch(dispatch, duration);

function chart(selection) {
    renderWatch.reset();
    selection.each(function(data) {
        var availableWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
            availableHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        container = d3.select(this);
        nv.utils.initSVG(container);

        if (stacked)
            data = d3.layout.stack()
                .offset('zero')
                .values(function(d){ return d.values })
                .y(getY)
            (data);

        //add series index and key to each data point for reference
        data.forEach(function(series, i) {
            series.values.forEach(function(point) {
                point.series = i;
                point.key = series.key;
            });
        });
        console.log('test')

        // HACK for negative value stacking
        if (stacked)
            data[0].values.map(function(d,i) {
                var posBase = 0, negBase = 0;
                data.map(function(d) {
                    var f = d.values[i]
                    f.size = Math.abs(f.y);
                    if (f.y<0)  {
                        f.y1 = negBase - f.size;
                        negBase = negBase - f.size;
                    } else
                    {
                        f.y1 = posBase;
                        posBase = posBase + f.size;
                    }
                });
            });

        // Setup Scales
        // remap and flatten the data for use in calculating the scales' domains
        var seriesData = (xDomain && yDomain) ? [] : // if we know xDomain and yDomain, no need to calculate
            data.map(function(d) {
                return d.values.map(function(d,i) {
                    return { x: getX(d,i), y: getY(d,i), y0: d.y0, y1: d.y1 }
                })
            });

        if (sortDescending) {
            x.domain(xDomain || d3.merge(seriesData).sort(function (a, b) { return Math.abs(b.y) - Math.abs(a.y) }).map(function(d) { return d.x }))
        } else {
            x.domain(xDomain || d3.merge(seriesData).map(function(d) { return d.x }))
        }
        x.rangeBands(xRange || [0, availableHeight], groupSpacing);


        y.domain(yDomain || d3.extent(d3.merge(seriesData).map(function(d) { return stacked ? (d.y > 0 ? d.y1 + d.y : d.y1 ) : d.y }).concat(forceY)))

        if (showValues && !stacked)
            y.range(yRange || [(y.domain()[0] < 0 ? valuePadding : 0), availableWidth - (y.domain()[1] > 0 ? valuePadding : 0) ]);
        else
            y.range(yRange || [0, availableWidth]);

        x0 = x0 || x;
        y0 = y0 || d3.scale.linear().domain(y.domain()).range([y(0),y(0)]);

        // Setup containers and skeleton of chart
        var wrap = d3.select(this).selectAll('g.nv-wrap.nv-multibarHorizontal').data([data]);
        var wrapEnter = wrap.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'nvd3 nv-wrap nv-multibarHorizontal');
        var defsEnter = wrapEnter.append('defs');
        var gEnter = wrapEnter.append('g');
        var g = wrap.select('g');

        gEnter.append('g').attr('class', 'nv-groups');
        wrap.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

        var groups = wrap.select('.nv-groups').selectAll('.nv-group')
            .data(function(d) { return d }, function(d,i) { return i });
        groups.enter().append('g')
            .style('stroke-opacity', 1e-6)
            .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);
        groups.exit().watchTransition(renderWatch, 'multibarhorizontal: exit groups')
            .style('stroke-opacity', 1e-6)
            .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
            .remove();
        groups
            .attr('class', function(d,i) { return 'nv-group nv-series-' + i })
            .classed('hover', function(d) { return d.hover })
            .style('fill', function(d,i){ return color(d, i) })
            .style('stroke', function(d,i){ return color(d, i) });
        groups.watchTransition(renderWatch, 'multibarhorizontal: groups')
            .style('stroke-opacity', 1)
            .style('fill-opacity', .75);

        var bars = groups.selectAll('g.nv-bar')
            .data(function(d) { 
                return d.values });
        bars.exit().remove();

        var barsEnter = bars.enter().append('g')
            .attr('transform', function(d,i,j) {
                console.log(i,j, (stacked ? 0 : (j * x.rangeBand() / data.length ) + x(getX(d,i))))
                return 'translate(' + y0(stacked ? d.y0 : 0) + ',' + (stacked ? 0 : (j * x.rangeBand() / data.length ) + x(getX(d,i))) + ')'
            });

        barsEnter.append('rect')
            .attr('width', 0)
            .attr('height', x.rangeBand() / (stacked ? 1 : data.length) )

        bars
            .on('mouseover', function(d,i) { //TODO: figure out why j works above, but not here
                d3.select(this).classed('hover', true);
                dispatch.elementMouseover({
                    data: d,
                    index: i,
                    color: d3.select(this).style("fill")
                });
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(d,i) {
                d3.select(this).classed('hover', false);
                dispatch.elementMouseout({
                    data: d,
                    index: i,
                    color: d3.select(this).style("fill")
                });
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(d,i) {
                dispatch.elementMouseout({
                    data: d,
                    index: i,
                    color: d3.select(this).style("fill")
                });
            })
            .on('mousemove', function(d,i) {
                dispatch.elementMousemove({
                    data: d,
                    index: i,
                    color: d3.select(this).style("fill")
                });
            })
            .on('click', function(d,i) {
                dispatch.elementClick({
                    data: d,
                    index: i,
                    color: d3.select(this).style("fill")
                });
                d3.event.stopPropagation();
            })
            .on('dblclick', function(d,i) {
                dispatch.elementDblClick({
                    data: d,
                    index: i,
                    color: d3.select(this).style("fill")
                });
                d3.event.stopPropagation();
            });

        if (getYerr(data[0],0)) {
            barsEnter.append('polyline');

            bars.select('polyline')
                .attr('fill', 'none')
                .attr('points', function(d,i) {
                    var xerr = getYerr(d,i)
                        , mid = 0.8 * x.rangeBand() / ((stacked ? 1 : data.length) * 2);
                    xerr = xerr.length ? xerr : [-Math.abs(xerr), Math.abs(xerr)];
                    xerr = xerr.map(function(e) { return y(e) - y(0); });
                    var a = [[xerr[0],-mid], [xerr[0],mid], [xerr[0],0], [xerr[1],0], [xerr[1],-mid], [xerr[1],mid]];
                    return a.map(function (path) { return path.join(',') }).join(' ');
                })
                .attr('transform', function(d,i) {
                    var mid = x.rangeBand() / ((stacked ? 1 : data.length) * 2);
                    return 'translate(' + (getY(d,i) < 0 ? 0 : y(getY(d,i)) - y(0)) + ', ' + mid + ')'
                });
        }

        barsEnter.append('text');

        if (showValues && !stacked) {
            bars.select('text')
                .attr('text-anchor', function(d,i) { return getY(d,i) < 0 ? 'end' : 'start' })
                .attr('y', x.rangeBand() / (data.length * 2))
                .attr('dy', '.32em')
                .text(function(d,i) {
                    var t = valueFormat(getY(d,i))
                        , yerr = getYerr(d,i);
                    if (yerr === undefined)
                        return t;
                    if (!yerr.length)
                        return t + '±' + valueFormat(Math.abs(yerr));
                    return t + '+' + valueFormat(Math.abs(yerr[1])) + '-' + valueFormat(Math.abs(yerr[0]));
                });
            bars.watchTransition(renderWatch, 'multibarhorizontal: bars')
                .select('text')
                .attr('x', function(d,i) { return getY(d,i) < 0 ? -4 : y(getY(d,i)) - y(0) + 4 })
        } else {
            bars.selectAll('text').text('');
        }

        if (showBarLabels && !stacked) {
            barsEnter.append('text').classed('nv-bar-label',true);
            bars.select('text.nv-bar-label')
                .attr('text-anchor', function(d,i) { return getY(d,i) < 0 ? 'start' : 'end' })
                .attr('y', x.rangeBand() / (data.length * 2))
                .attr('dy', '.32em')
                .text(function(d,i) { return getX(d,i) });
            bars.watchTransition(renderWatch, 'multibarhorizontal: bars')
                .select('text.nv-bar-label')
                .attr('x', function(d,i) { return getY(d,i) < 0 ? y(0) - y(getY(d,i)) + 4 : -4 });
        }
        else {
            bars.selectAll('text.nv-bar-label').text('');
        }

        bars
            .attr('class', function(d,i) { return getY(d,i) < 0 ? 'nv-bar negative' : 'nv-bar positive'})

        if (barColor) {
            if (!disabled) disabled = data.map(function() { return true });
            bars
                .style('fill', function(d,i,j) { return d3.rgb(barColor(d,i)).darker(  disabled.map(function(d,i) { return i }).filter(function(d,i){ return !disabled[i]  })[j]   ).toString(); })
                .style('stroke', function(d,i,j) { return d3.rgb(barColor(d,i)).darker(  disabled.map(function(d,i) { return i }).filter(function(d,i){ return !disabled[i]  })[j]   ).toString(); });
        }

        if (stacked)
            bars.watchTransition(renderWatch, 'multibarhorizontal: bars')
                .attr('transform', function(d,i) {
                    return 'translate(' + y(d.y1) + ',' + x(getX(d,i)) + ')'
                })
                .select('rect')
                .attr('width', function(d,i) {
                    return Math.abs(y(getY(d,i) + d.y0) - y(d.y0))
                })
                .attr('height', x.rangeBand() );
        else
            bars.watchTransition(renderWatch, 'multibarhorizontal: bars')
                .attr('transform', function(d,i) {
                    //TODO: stacked must be all positive or all negative, not both?
                    return 'translate(' +
                        (getY(d,i) < 0 ? y(getY(d,i)) : y(0))
                        + ',' +
                        (d.series * x.rangeBand() / data.length
                            +
                            x(getX(d,i)) )
                        + ')'
                })
                .select('rect')
                .attr('height', x.rangeBand() / data.length )
                .attr('width', function(d,i) {
                    return Math.max(Math.abs(y(getY(d,i)) - y(0)),1)
                });

        //store old scales for use in transitions on update
        x0 = x.copy();
        y0 = y.copy();

    });

    renderWatch.renderEnd('multibarHorizontal immediate');
    return chart;
}

//============================================================
// Expose Public Variables
//------------------------------------------------------------

chart.dispatch = dispatch;

chart.options = nv.utils.optionsFunc.bind(chart);

chart._options = Object.create({}, {
    // simple options, just get/set the necessary values
    width:   {get: function(){return width;}, set: function(_){width=_;}},
    height:  {get: function(){return height;}, set: function(_){height=_;}},
    x:       {get: function(){return getX;}, set: function(_){getX=_;}},
    y:       {get: function(){return getY;}, set: function(_){getY=_;}},
    yErr:       {get: function(){return getYerr;}, set: function(_){getYerr=_;}},
    xScale:  {get: function(){return x;}, set: function(_){x=_;}},
    yScale:  {get: function(){return y;}, set: function(_){y=_;}},
    xDomain: {get: function(){return xDomain;}, set: function(_){xDomain=_;}},
    yDomain: {get: function(){return yDomain;}, set: function(_){yDomain=_;}},
    xRange:  {get: function(){return xRange;}, set: function(_){xRange=_;}},
    yRange:  {get: function(){return yRange;}, set: function(_){yRange=_;}},
    forceY:  {get: function(){return forceY;}, set: function(_){forceY=_;}},
    stacked: {get: function(){return stacked;}, set: function(_){stacked=_;}},
    showValues: {get: function(){return showValues;}, set: function(_){showValues=_;}},
    // this shows the group name, seems pointless?
    //showBarLabels:    {get: function(){return showBarLabels;}, set: function(_){showBarLabels=_;}},
    disabled:     {get: function(){return disabled;}, set: function(_){disabled=_;}},
    id:           {get: function(){return id;}, set: function(_){id=_;}},
    valueFormat:  {get: function(){return valueFormat;}, set: function(_){valueFormat=_;}},
    valuePadding: {get: function(){return valuePadding;}, set: function(_){valuePadding=_;}},
    groupSpacing:{get: function(){return groupSpacing;}, set: function(_){groupSpacing=_;}},

    // options that require extra logic in the setter
    margin: {get: function(){return margin;}, set: function(_){
        margin.top    = _.top    !== undefined ? _.top    : margin.top;
        margin.right  = _.right  !== undefined ? _.right  : margin.right;
        margin.bottom = _.bottom !== undefined ? _.bottom : margin.bottom;
        margin.left   = _.left   !== undefined ? _.left   : margin.left;
    }},
    duration: {get: function(){return duration;}, set: function(_){
        duration = _;
        renderWatch.reset(duration);
    }},
    color:  {get: function(){return color;}, set: function(_){
        color = nv.utils.getColor(_);
    }},
    barColor:  {get: function(){return barColor;}, set: function(_){
        barColor = _ ? nv.utils.getColor(_) : null;
    }},
    sortDescending: {get: function(){return sortDescending;}, set: function(_){sortDescending=_;}},

});

nv.utils.initOptions(chart);

return chart;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer to [this request](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1711)? (for stacked bar charts)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to just sort the array before you pass it to the chart?  That is what I did with 1 line and it works like a charm.  It is way cleaner and easier to have complex sorting depending on the data.

Comment: Are you asking or telling?

Comment: Not straightforward for a *multi*barchart.